# Loading Html page and modifying a section

Tags: asp.net, html, embedded-resource

I need to load an external web (not local) page into my site (some link), but only a part of it.
What are the options for doing so?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on whether or not the external page is local, or on a different domain. If it's local, you can use $.load() in the jQuery library. This has an optional parameter to specify which element in the remote-dom to load it:

```
$("#links").load("/Main_Page #jq-p-Getting-Started li");
```

If the page is on another domain, you'll need a proxy script. You can do this with PHP and the [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) (php port of jQuery) library. You'll just use file_get_contents() to get the actual remote-dom, and then pull out the elements you want based on jQuery-like selectors.

Comment: The page is not local, are there any librarys as such for asp.net?

Answer (score 0):

```
$f = fopen('http://www.quran.az/2/255', 'r');
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

To load a web page in .Net, use the HttpWebRequest class.

Example taken from MSDN, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28classic%29.aspx):

```
    private string StringGetWebPage(String uri)
    {
        const int bufSizeMax = 65536; // max read buffer size conserves memory
        const int bufSizeMin = 8192;  // min size prevents numerous small reads
        StringBuilder sb;

        // A WebException is thrown if HTTP request fails
        try 
        {
            // Create an HttpWebRequest using WebRequest.Create (see .NET docs)!
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

            // Execute the request and obtain the response stream
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            // Content-Length header is not trustable, but makes a good hint.
            // Responses longer than int size will throw an exception here!
            int length = (int)response.ContentLength;

            // Use Content-Length if between bufSizeMax and bufSizeMin
            int bufSize = bufSizeMin;
            if (length > bufSize)
                bufSize = length > bufSizeMax ? bufSizeMax : length;

            // Allocate buffer and StringBuilder for reading response
            byte[] buf = new byte[bufSize];
            sb = new StringBuilder(bufSize);

            // Read response stream until end
            while ((length = responseStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length)) != 0)
                sb.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf, 0, length));

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            sb = new StringBuilder(ex.Message);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
}
```

Note that this will return *the entire page* and not just a portion of it. You'll then need to sift through the page to find the information you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the whole page as Michael Todd outlined, you will likely need to either use substring methods for a static means to slice up the content or you can use regex's for a more dynamic way to grab the content.  An intro article on Regex's in ASP.Net can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972966.aspx).  Good luck!

Comment: OP could also try using `XmlDocument` to parse the page and get specific nodes.